# Sustaining value in specified range

Tags: c++, math, assembly, binary

Lets say i have a point with its position on 2d plane.
This point is going to change it position randomly, but thats not the point, so lets assume that it has its own velocity and its moving on plane with restricted width and height;
So after a while of movement this point is going to reach plane boundary.
But its not allowed to leave plane.

So now i can check point position each frame to see is it reached bound or not.

if(point.x>bound.xMax)point.x=bound.xMax

if i want point to teleport itself to second side of plane i can simply :

point.x = point.x%bound.xMax;

but then i need to store point position in integers.

For 10 milion values on my corei7 1.6 both solutions
have similar timings. 41ms vs 47 on second,
so there is no sense in using modulo function in that case, its faster to just check value.

But, is there any kind of trick to make it faster?
Multiple threads for iterating array approach is not a solution.

Maybe i can scale my bound value to some wierd value and for example discard a part of binary interpretation of position value.

And if there is some trick to do it i think that somebody did it before me :)
Do you know any kind of solution that could help me?

Comment: In floating-point values you couldn't just "drop" some bits in binary representation, because then you will just lose some significant numbers.

Comment: Why not simply use `fmod()` for floating-point modulo? I'm pretty sure you can't optimize more that that on such primitive calculations

Answer (score 1):

If there is some way you can add information around the plane coordinates you could very well make a "border" around the plane which contains a value that is identified as "out of boundaries". For example if you have a 10x10 board, make it 12x12 and use the 2 extra rows and columns to insert that information.

Now you can do (pseudo-code):
    IF point IN board IS "out of boundaries value" THEN
    do your thing
    END IF

Note that this method is only an optimization if your point has both x and y values (my assumption on your case).